# Fields de serializers que hagan referencia a si mismos

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Estoy desarrollando como proyecto personal una red social similar a Instagram,
tengo ya mi modelo de perfil, el problema que tengo no es relacionado con el modelo en si si no con los serializers. Es con el campo de los seguidores, que como hace referencia al mismo perfil no se como hacerlo siguiendo la filosofia de DRY he buscado en la documentacion de Django REST Framework y no he encotrado nada referente, espero y ustedes compañeros de Stack Overflow me puedan ayudar.

Estos son los fields de seguidores y seguidos.

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(
    'self',
    related_name='following',
    symmetrical=False
)
```

y este es de momento mi serializer

```
class ProfileModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Profile Model Serializer."""

    # Followers ??
    # Following ??

    class Meta:
        """Metadata class."""

        model = Profile

        fields = (
            'website', 'biography',
            'picture'
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'followers', 'following'
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final he terminado con varias respuestas que me han convecido lo suficiente, pero dado que no puedo usarlas todas al mismo tiempo me he decantado por una sola.

---

**Hyperlinked Relations**

Basicamente son urls que al ser accedidas contienen los datos que queremos, y facilitan muchisimo hacer relaciones del objeto en si mismo, ya que no tienes que reescribir el serializer para lo mismo. En codigo esto se veia mas o menos asi.

**Serializer**

```
class ProfileModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Handles serialization of the data related to a profile model."""

    followers = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='profiles-detail'
    )

    following = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='profiles-detail'
    )
    class Meta:
        """Metadata class"""

        # Same data as before.
```

**Pros**

- Le ahorran consumo de red al consumidor del api
- Te ahorran tener que escribir dos serializers para lo mismo.
- Son mas faciles de procesar para el api en si.

**Contras**

- Si los followers(o following), son muchos terminamos con un problema de red.

---

**Django Rest Framework Recursive**

Es una libreria que nos permite serializer arboles de una manera muy facil, o mejor dicho relaciones recursivas haciendo uso de un field llamado **RecursiveField**
que nos facilita de una manera genial la vida. [Github](https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive)

El principal problema es que no se puede limitar(o al menos no con la libreria original) la profundidad de la relacion, asi que tenemos que modificar la libreria para que se adapte a esta nueva funcionalidad, esta modficacion no la he hecho yo, la hizo alguien mas de Stack Overflow, les dejo el link a su modificacion en el foro de Stack Overflow. [Modificacion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376894/django-rest-framework-nested-self-referential-objects)

Hay un error en el codigo de la modificacion, el cual nos deja con el mismo problema de la profundidad pero afortunadamente me di cuenta de ello y lo arregle, asi que si gustan pueden copiar esta solucion directamente desde aqui. El error estaba en la linea 43 y la solucion es la siguiente.

```
# Codigo original.
serializer._recurse_lvl = lvl + is_through or not has_through

# Codigo Modificado.
serializer._recurse_lvl = lvl + (is_through or not has_through)
```

PD: En el mismo issue en el que encontre estos datos el autor recomendaba limitar la profundidad del queryset antes de pasarlo al serializer para evitar estos errores, pero sinceramente desconozco como hacer eso, si alguien tiene conocimiento de como acortar esta profundidad a la hora de obtener el queryset estaria agradecido de que lo compartiera. [Issue](https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive/issues/12)

Ahora si, sin mas preambulo pasemos directamente al codigo.

**Modificacion para soportar limite de profundidad.**

```
class RecursiveField(serializers.Serializer):
        """
        Can be used as a field within another serializer,
        to produce nested-recursive relationships. Works with
        through models, and limited and/or arbitrarily deep trees.
        """
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self._recurse_through = kwargs.pop('through_serializer', None)
            self._recurse_max = kwargs.pop('max_depth', None)
            self._recurse_view = kwargs.pop('reverse_name', None)
            self._recurse_attr = kwargs.pop('reverse_attr', None)
            self._recurse_many = kwargs.pop('many', False)

            super(RecursiveField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def to_representation(self, value):
            parent = self.parent
            if isinstance(parent, serializers.ListSerializer):
                parent = parent.parent

            lvl = getattr(parent, '_recurse_lvl', 1)
            max_lvl = self._recurse_max or getattr(parent, '_recurse_max', None)

            # Defined within RecursiveField(through_serializer=A)
            serializer_class = self._recurse_through
            is_through = has_through = True

            # Informed by previous serializer (for through m2m)
            if not serializer_class:
                is_through = False
                serializer_class = getattr(parent, '_recurse_next', None)

            # Introspected for cases without through models.
            if not serializer_class:
                has_through = False
                serializer_class = parent.__class__

            if is_through or not max_lvl or lvl <= max_lvl: 
                serializer = serializer_class(
                    value, many=self._recurse_many, context=self.context)

                # Propagate hereditary attributes.
                serializer._recurse_lvl = lvl + is_through or not has_through
                serializer._recurse_max = max_lvl

                if is_through:
                    # Delay using parent serializer till next lvl.
                    serializer._recurse_next = parent.__class__

                return serializer.data
            else:
                view = self._recurse_view or self.context['request'].resolver_match.url_name
                attr = self._recurse_attr or 'id'
                return reverse(view, args=[getattr(value, attr)],
                               request=self.context['request'])
```

**Serializer**

```
class ProfileModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """"Handles serialization of the data related to a profile model."""

    followers = RecursiveField(read_only=True, many=True, max_depth=1, reverse_name='profiles-detail')
    following = RecursiveField(read_only=True, many=True, max_depth=1, reverse_name='profiles-detail')

    class Meta:
        """Metadata class."""

        # Same data as before.
```

**Pros**

- Facil de entender.
- Usas la filosofia DRY

**Contras**

- Dificil de manejar para el consumidor de la api en terminos de velocidad de red.
- Son pesados de procesar.
- No puedes simplemente declararlo como una dependencia del proyecto, si no que tienes que usar trabajo que esta construido sobre esta libreria.
- Al final terminas usando Hyperlinked Relations, asi que tampoco tiene mucho caso.

---

**Una url por aparte para los followers y following(Implementacion final)**

Dado que pueden llegar a ser muchos y las peticiones van a ser constantes no es descabellado darle una url especial a estos campos, ya que asi podemos paginarlos y ademas de eso dar simplemente los links a los perfiles. Lo cual es excelente, asi que pongamonos manos a la obra y pasemos de una vez al codigo, que esto no requiere de mucha ciencia.

**Serializers**

```
class ProfileModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Handles profile data serialization."""

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('website', 'biography', 'picture')


class RelatedProfilePaginationSerializer(LimitOffsetPagination):
    """Handles serialization and pagination of the fields followers and following of a profile."""

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        """Handles serialization of the related profiles."""

        super(RelatedProfilePaginationSerializer, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
        related_profiles_urls = [
            reverse(
                'profiles-detail',
                args=[related_profile.user.username]
            )
            for related_profile in queryset
        ]
        return related_profiles_urls[self.offset:self.offset + self.limit]
```

**Views**

```
class ProfileModelViewset(GenericViewSet, RetrieveModelMixin):
    """Profile Model Related Views."""

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'username'
    serializer_class = ProfileModelSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def followers(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        """Handles returning all the followers using HyperLinked relations."""

        profile = self.get_object()

        followers = profile.followers.all()

        return self.paginate_followers_or_following(followers, request)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def following(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        """Handles returning all the following users using Hyperlinked relations."""

        profile = self.get_object()
        following = profile.following.all()

        return self.paginate_followers_or_following(following, request)

    def paginate_followers_or_following(self, queryset, request):
        """Return followers or following pagination based on action."""

        assert self.action in ['followers', 'following']

        paginator = RelatedProfilePaginationSerializer()
        data = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)

        return paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
```

**Pros**

- Puedes usar filosofia DRY
- La paginacion de nuevo al rescate, ya que facilita la consulta de usuarios con multiples seguidores
- Son faciles de computar

**Contras**

- Tal vez, puedan saturarte de peticiones(soy nuevo en esto de las apis asi que desconozco cuanto es el limite correcto de peticiones por segundo), aunque esto puede tener solucion serializandolo de una manera normal exponiendo todos los datos de los followers y following.

---

**Conclusion**

No es facil serializar relaciones a un objeto en si mismo, pero todo en la programacion tiene solucion, solo es cuestion de descomponer el problema en problemas mas pequenos y asi solucionarlo de a poco.

Si tienes alguna sugerencia para mejorar el codigo te invito a comentarlo, en serio que me ayudaria muchisimo y si tienes alguna otra solucion que sea epica ponla en las respuestas tambien seria genial. Un saludo